# How to achieve Customized replication function?

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

This is my issue.

I have a server DB and a local SQL Express DB installed on few clients. For every 2 hours I need to pull records from server DB to local DB. But the catch is I want values from the server DB to start from a specific number and then till the end of the records that are available [Edit] and the process continues.

Say for example:

[Edit]
At very beginning, the Server DB say has following data.

10
20

On the Local DB also (after transactional replication with update) i shall be having the following data.

10
20

Left say, After 2 hours on the Server DB the data will be following...

10
20
30
40
50

Now, on my local SQLExpress DB after 2 hours I should copy the data values ONLY 
30
40
50 
and the earlier values i.e. 10 & 20 should be deleted ONLY ON THE LOCAL SQL EXPRESS DB.

Along with this, if the values is editing on the replicated Db the same should be affected back to the server DB.

<strike>I have seen this link [How do I achieve this sort of replication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075905/how-do-i-achieve-this-sort-of-replication) but it I haven't yet given a full thought as my architecture is different to use Transactional replication at this point of time.</strike>

<strike>At present I plan to get the data from Server DB to a DATASET and then dump it on to my local DB.</strike>

[Edit]

**I did follow the suggestion of using Transactional replication & Transactional replication with updates provided in this post. Though the replication is working fine but the issue now is if i delete the row/data from my SQL Express DB the row/data is also getting deleted on my SQL Server DB which I DO NOT WANT - How to resolve this.**

Any suggestions on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at transactional replication. It does exactly what you are looking for. Check out my introductory series here: [Stairway to SQL Server Replication](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72401/)

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. But I have a disconnected network scenario where the clients may be disconnected for un-foreseen scenarios. In this scenarios also do you think it holds good?

Comment: Not to put words in Sebastian's mouth, but yes. You can schedule the distribution agent (rather than having it run continuously) and it will pick up where it left off in case of disconnectedness.

Comment: So this means, I can have a differential download plus I can also program to delete the previous records in my SQLExpress so that only fresh set of new downloads will be pouplated in my SQLExpress.

Comment: @BenThul is there any sample project which can demostrate this feature?

Comment: @aioracle: There's no sample project, as that's just the way the distribution agent works. Replication keeps track of what commands have and haven't been delivered to a particular subscriber and the distribution agent is smart enough to pick up where it left off.

Comment: In this case you should go with a pull subscription model.

Comment: @SebastianMeine I did use the pull subscription model. The challenge now is, everything is working but when dataset is deleted on the subscriber it gets reflected back to the publisher which I want to stop it. I don't want any data to be deleted on the publisher. Also I did go through your articles and it did assist me a lot. BTW, i am using Transactional Replication with Updateable subscription.

Comment: Not to jump in here, but even if it was possible to delete at the subscriber and not have the change propagate upstream to the publisher, this isn't a great idea. The reason being that now the publisher and subscriber are out of sync. If/when that record gets updated or deleted at the publisher, replication (specifically distribution) will error out because it won't be able to find that record at the subscriber. So you'd either have to customize the sprocs responsible for updates/deletes to make that okay or handle it some other way. The alternative, of course, is don't do that.

Comment: I must agree with @BenThul here. Replication does not take it well if a record on the publisher does not exist on the subscriber. You can make this work by manually providing the procedures that are used by replication to actually apply the data changes, but that is a lot of work, that has to be repeated for each table.